# AVPlayer sometimes fails to play video

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I use AVPlayer to play video.

Sometimes users can't play video, they have an infinite loading..
(solved if they restart their phone).

it's appear over 3G/4G network, but never over WIFI.

I've traced the issue, and it appear the app doesn't valid the IF condition to play the video :

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*) path ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context
{

    if(context == PlayerItemTimeRangesObservationContext)
    {
       NSArray *timeRanges = self.player.currentItem.loadedTimeRanges;
       if ([timeRanges count] > 0)
       {
            //play video..
       }
    }
}
```

The most strange is that users need to restart their phone ! Close the app don't solve the issue.

If the user have this issue over 4G network, switch to WIFI solve the issue, but switch again to 4G and issue come back.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Did you try to restart the app only? Closing the app moves it into background but does not necessarily stop anything going on within your code.

Comment: Yes i did, restart the app doesnt work.

Comment: getting same issue. but its not depends on network.. if you found solution den plz share